# Intuit Open authentication and email addresses

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

At http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0010_Getting_Started/0030_Integrate_your_app/0030_Signing_Into_and_out_of_Intuit_From_Within_Your_App/Sign-in/Implement_SSO_and_OpenID_in_Your_App

it says the following:

"Intuit does not verify the user email address associated with the user's OpenID account.  Therefore, do not use the email address for authentication and do not link user accounts based on email address."

What does it mean "do not use the email address for authentication"? I mean, isn't the user already authenticated, through OpenId.

Also it says that the user email address is not verified. But what if my app needs to send an email to a user that has logged through OpenId. How can I be sure the user will actually get the email? What is the recommended pattern to handle that?

Thanks

EDIT: also, can I use the email to uniquely identify a user, and if not, what should I use to uniquely identify a user from the open id response?

EDIT 2: also, is the developer charged when a user logs in with open id and the 36 day trial expires? Or is it just when using the "Connect to quickbooks" that the developer is charged, in which case, open id authentication itself is free?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clement,
It means when a customer goes to the Intuit Appcenter and creates an account the email is not verified immediately, so you cannot single sign on a user based only on their email address if they already have an account in your system. You need to prompt them to login one time to map the two accounts.

If they are completely new then you can auto provision an account on your side and single sign them in, if you require the customer to verify their email address then you can send them a verification email.

thanks
Jarred

Comment: Right, I think what you're talking about in your first paragraph is the case where the user doesn't even have a quickbooks account and actually register through the app center AND at the same time they also have previsouly registered with my app already. Right ? So then when you say to prompt the user to map the 2 accounts, do you mean to ask the user for his password on the account registered on my app to make sure he actually "owns" that email??? Regarding the second paragraph, is it against the requirement to prevent the user from usnig the app until the email is verified? Thanks

Comment: correct, you want to ask for their password to map the accounts. It is not against the requirements to prevent them until they verify, certain security compliances require you to validate email first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more thing to confirm, the user can only sign up directly through the app center for Quickbooks Windows right? In the case of Quickbooks Online, I guess the user would first have to create a Quickbooks online, and only then can the user go to the Quickbooks online appcenter when logging in Quickooks online?

Comment: An end customer can sign up from anywhere, either Appcenter or your site. In the case of QBO they will be prompted to select their QBO Company, if they dont have one they will be prompted to create a free trial first then return and select it.

Comment: Jarred - You should really explain that better in your documentation because it is confusing the way it is worded in the docs